# Coverflow recenters itself while scrolling, when OnItemSelected changes other views

Tags: android, gallery, coverflow, baseadapter, android-cursoradapter

Dear Stackoverflow community,

i have a pretty wierd problem. First of all i built some kind of a "chooser" activity, which is nothing more than a WheelView on the left side, a Coverflow in the center and another (smaller) coverflow beneath that. Btw. a CoverFlow is a Gallery with some logic overridden.

The center coverflow uses a BaseAdapter. I've created some set of Lists and each time my coverflow gets new content, i create a new instance of BaseAdapter with one of the lists. In my case this is done, when selecting an item in the lower CoverFlow. So i implemented an OnItemSelectedListener, to check when that happens. Scrolling this coverflow causes the view to "notifyDataSetChanged" always and change the adapter in some case. Now this works like a charm.

As i have lots of objects in this chooser (the center coverflow), i decided to continue using a CursorAdapter to increase performance. Now the CursorAdapter doesn't seem to have a notifyDataSetChanged() method, so i copied the same code-logic as the BaseAdapter and used this in mine. The lower Coverflow still uses the same adapter (in this case a ListAdapter, implementing a SpinnerAdapter). Now - when doing the exact same logic, the lower coverflow recenters itself after each notifyDataSetChanged() call on the center CoverFlowAdapter. I seriously don't get it. I will not post the whole logic here, as that would be about 5 classes, but the point in question is this one:

```
   private OnItemSelectedListener itemSelListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
//          if(!selectedByClicking){
            switchModelType(arg1.getId());          
//          }
    }

private void switchModelType(int id){
    int oldMode = mode;
    mode = id;
    for(int i = 0; i < currentColors.length; i++){
        if(currentColors[i] != null)
        currentColors[i].isSelected = false;
    }
    if(currentColors[mode] != null)
    currentColors[mode].isSelected = true;
    if(coverFlow.getAdapter() != null){
        ((SelectionObjectCursorAdapter)     
            coverFlow.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
             //         if(decorIsWooden)
             //             checkIfWoodDecorAdapter(oldMode);

    }
}
```

The lower CoverFlow is not touched at any point in this part of code, nor is it anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.. Though i searched for this error for days, i got the solution now.

The problem was, that i created the lower coverflow programatically, thus setting the height of both with layout_height programatically. Each time i changed the adapter of the coverflow, it called it's measure method, thus also calling the measure method of the lower coverflow (since they are linked by layout_height). Setting this in the XML, adding the layout_sum to the super linear layout got rid of the problem.

Thank god..